# What was the first movie entirely shot from a first person POV?

Tags: film-techniques, first-appearance

The movie [Hardcore Henry](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3072482/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) [claims](http://io9.gizmodo.com/inside-the-worlds-first-pov-action-movie-everybody-has-1769394094) to be the "the world’s first fully first-person action movie", that is, it is entirely shot from the protagonists first person point of view (POV).

But I don't think this is the first time a movie has been shot entirely from a first person POV. So what *was* the first movie shot from a first person POV?

Comment: From 1934: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Firebird_(1934_film)

Comment: @Decypher I've not seen the movie, but the Wikipedia page suggests that only *some* of it (i.e. the murder scene) is shot in the first person.

Comment: Maybe you should add 'entirely' to the question title and the last sentence, it would be more clear.

Comment: @Gandalf The question is about POV not about whether you get t see the protagonist So being themselves in a mirror doesn't invalidate the POV.

Comment: Below find the movie I originally saw circa 1965 on TV. It struck me for the POV, but that is about all.

Comment: Not a movie, but the British comedy, [Peep Show](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0387764/)  is filmed like that.

Comment: Hardcore Henry is *way* more entertaining that the POV technique might lead you to expect. And it has already been imitated (despite only just being released in the UK) by [Hard Line aka Dead Rush](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4899510/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)

Comment: technically the movie unfriended is shot in first person but it is not revealed until the end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***[Lady in the Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_in_the_Lake)*** (1947) was a *film noir* shot entirely in the first person POV, with the exception of 2 scenes where the protagonist broke the fourth wall to address the audience directly.

Taken from the Raymond Chandler novel of the same name, it was adapted to the screen and directed by Robert Montgomery, who also "starred" as the character Phillip Marlowe.

Wiki: "MGM promoted the film with the claim that it was the ***first of its kind and the most revolutionary style of film*** since the introduction of the talkies".

I couldn't find another, similarly filmed movie to refute that claim. As many people complained when this movie came out, that it was distracting POV, it has never been a popular film technique. It's rather more successful in "Shooter" video games.

[image]

Comment: A good example (and I have seen it). But was it *first* and are there other examples?

Comment: It's not a really successful form of filming. Most people find it distracting, so I guess it wasn't used much, unless you count  those "Blair Witch" rip-offs.

Comment: Things like Blair Witch are hand-held camera POV not, strictly, individual persons's eye POV. That's a subtle distinction.